# Add Xib file as CameraOverlay to create a Custom Camera UI (XAMARIN.iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, camera-overlay

I m trying to create a camera Custom UI (somewhat like Instagram camera view )

Can Some one help me with adding .xib (layout for my cameraOverlayView) as cameraOverlayView .

inside -> ViewDidLoad()

```
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        var imagePickerControl = new UIImagePickerController();
        imagePickerControl.SourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
        imagePickerControl.ShowsCameraControls = true;
        //Code lines needed to add the xib "CameraOverlayView.xib" as uiview to pass next line  
        imagePickerControl.CameraOverlayView = ;

        var imagePickerDelegate = new CameraImagePicker(this);
        imagePickerControl.Delegate = imagePickerDelegate;
        NavigationController.PresentModalViewController(imagePickerControl, true);
```

I was refering to 
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/templates/using_the_ios_view_xib_template/

But I was unable to add the xib as my CameraOverlay

Ask for related code if needed ..
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add the `Create` method described in that tutorial? You need to inflate the xib into a `UIView` and that is your `CameraOverlayView`. The tutorial explains how to inflate the xib using a static `Create` method.

Comment: So according to you what approach should follow to add this xib as my CameraOverlay and even handle my Camera buttons (take picture and cancel ) which are on XIB layout.

Comment: Remember that a XIB creates a `UIView` - that's what they do. A XIB exists purely to be inflated into a `UIView` (or a subclass of `UIView`). (When you load a `UIViewController` from XIB, it's basically loading that XIB as the `View`). If there are buttons in your XIB, then you need to connect those to outlets in your XIB's code behind. You need to use the XIB's code behind (that C# file). Once the buttons are exposed as properties, you can assign events or do whatever you want from code.

Comment: Is there any syntax so that i can directly pass this xib UIview to  <here>                "imagePickerControl.CameraOverlayView = <here>;" some working code snippet for this would be very useful .

Comment: Use the `Create` method from the article you linked... `imagePickerControl.CameraOverlayView = MyFancyXib.Create()`.

Comment: In CameraOverlayView.cs (the UIView class ):: `>>var arr = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("CameraOverlayView", null, null);
   >>var v = Runtime.GetNSObject<CameraOverlayView>(arr.ValueAt(0));`
in these lines error that Runtime is not present in present context  when I fix it adding `using Mono` there is another error:  'Runtime' doesnot contain 'GetNSObject'.  how can i overcome this roadbloack.
thanks in advance   [>> is for nxt line code]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121656/discussion-between-samridhgupta-and-dylansturg).

Comment: Chat is blocked for me. Sorry. Simply use `using ObjCRuntime;` instead of `using Mono;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot , now i m able to view the overlay , but still unable to handle the button clicks..

Comment: Did you add outlets for your buttons? Are you adding an event handler to their `TouchUpInside` event?